# Run and simulate Android code online on web

Tags: android, emulation

I've decided to learn android. I've installed [android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) on my laptop. Unfortunately, my system has low RAM to process its code.
Is there any website that allows me to run and emulate my code there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any web site that allows to run and emulate my code there

There's fresh release from GenyMobile that let's you run Genymotion on AWS instance and access via browser. See: https://www.genymotion.com/aws/

There're some related videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Us0Uj4bcCVA

Answer (score 0):

Java is very RAM greedy, you'll need a very good machine to code AND test on an Android emulator...

If you are learning Java, you can first try some basic console or swing applications.

The Android emulator is only useful to test your app on a large variety of devices (tv, wear, tablet) and Android version (Lollipop, Nougat,...). If you just want to learn, you can use your own phone to try your apps. You just need to go to your carrier's website and look for drivers, or use those included in the Android SDK Manager.

Comment: Hmm... `8 GB` RAM and `Core i5` CPU was more than enough for my `Windows 7` laptop (also maybe get `SSD 128 GB` storage, but you need probably more RAM for `Windows 10`+).

Comment: Oh... just remembered my SSD gets shared and used as RAM (with configurable size), so, I have `11 GB` RAM in total !!